# SharePoint Online - Setup Question (Publishing Portal v Team Site)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, online

The company I work for (Education Institution) is currently preparing for a Office 365 tenancy migration due to Academic Pricing offered by Microsoft.

I have setup SharePoint online before but only using the default Team Site root site collection that was created when the tenancy is created. (bunch of sub sites etc) I am now trying to determine if this is the best approach in contrast to a Publishing Portal.

I was originally going to setup the root site collection as a publishing portal but than found the below article that Microsoft doesn't allow a publishing portal at the root. http://blog.danielsmon.com/2014/12/17/sharepoint-online-publishing-portal-template-not-allowed-at-the-root-url/

There has been workarounds for this as suggested in the article, but did mention issues with doing this and it seems like if Microsoft wanted you to be able to do this, than they would allow it.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2674732

Further suggested in the article is to simply create a publishing portal in a different site collection and than just do a page redirection from your normal root team site collection to the publishing portal which appears to work fine.

My question is does anybody have experience with using team sites (the only method I have used) over using the publishing portal template. We are an organisation of around 400 staff and have in total around 300GB of SharePoint data spread over 20 sub sites, and this is growing quickly. I need to setup all of the sites/pages from scratch and from what I was reading a publishing portal will minimise the pain of this process. (the sites will be very similar)

Our current SharePoint is a mess and I want to get this right considering we have a clean state to start on. Can anyone please offer advise on what their recommendation for the root site collection would be considering the limitations suggested earlier, and any other general advise for the planning and setup.